# Using tornado ioloop for loading big python pickle file into memory

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I am building a testing server that loads up a huge pickle file (took about 30s) when an endpoint is hit. My goal is to update it to load the pickle as a python object into memory in the background when the tornado web server boots up as a separate thread.  So when the endpoint is hit, it either finds it in the memory or it waits until the thread has completed the loading. That way will make the boot-up much faster.

I am here seeking some recommendation on what's the best way to add async to make this operation working.

**my_server.py**

```
    import tornado.ioloop
    import tornado.web

    from my_class import MyClass

    class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            m = MyClass.get_foobar_object_by_name('foobar')
            self.write("Hello, world")

    def make_app():
        return tornado.web.Application([
            (r"/", MainHandler),
        ])

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = make_app()
        app.listen(8888)
        MyClass.load()  # takes 30s to load
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

**my_class.py**

```
    class MyClass(object):
        pickle_path = '/opt/some/path/big_file.pickle'
        foobar_map = None

        @staticmethod
        def load():
            # this step takes about 30s to load
            MyClass.foobar_map = pickle.load(open(local_path, 'rb'))

        @staticmethod
        def get_foobar_object_by_name(foobar_name):
            if MyClass.foobar_map is None:
                MyClass.load()
            return MyClass.foobar_map.get(foobar_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pickle` module has a synchronous interface, so the only way to run it asynchronously is to run it on another thread. Using the new `IOLoop.run_in_executor` interface in Tornado 5.0:

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import RequestHandler
from tornado.locks import Lock

class MyClass:
    lock = Lock()

    @staticmethod
    async def load():
        async with MyClass.lock():
            # Check again inside the lock to make sure we only do this once. 
            if MyClass.foobar_map is None:
                MyClass.foobar_map = await IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, pickle.load, open(local_path, 'rb'))

    @staticmethod
    async def get_foobar_object_by_name(foobar_name):
        if MyClass.foobar_map is None:
            await MyClass.load()
        return MyClass.foobar_map.get(foobar_name)

class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
        m = await MyClass.get_foobar_object_by_name('foobar')
        self.write("Hello, world")
```

Note that `async` is contagious: anything that calls an `async` function also needs to be `async` and use `await`.